# How do I clone/copy/duplicate a pull request in Github

Tags: git, github

I have a pull request that I want to create a copy of. Like another pull request that does the exact same thing but exists as a separate pull request.

The reason is that I want to merge the two copies into two different branches. And I don't want to pull the stuff locally, merge into another local branch bla bla.

Does Github provide this feature?

Comment: I think you have to do it locally :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, **no**, GitHub does not provide the feature to duplicate a pull request. It actually has the opposite feature and allows you to [mark a duplicate pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/marking-issues-or-pull-requests-as-a-duplicate#marking-duplicates).

This, however, won't stop you from making as many duplicate PRs as you wish. It's not clear from your question if you want to create a PR from `feature/breanch1` to `feature/branch2` AND to `feature/branch3` or to have two copies of `feature/branch1` that will have separate PRs to other branches, but as long as all of the branches are pushed to remote, you can easily use the GitHub UI to create all the PRs you want.

Just be sure to set the `base` and `compare` of the PRs correctly.

Here is an example of the PR page (which I bet you are familiar with) just to give more context.

[image]